# Angular - get an element by reference variable in a service

Tags: angular5

Is it possible to get an element / component by the exposed reference variable (globally, no child-parent relation)?

Right now, on the relevant component's ngOnInit, I am registering them in a map in the service but it requires injecting ElementRef and registration in every single component.

Thanks.